# Read a matrix from a txt file

Tags: java, matrix, file-io

I have a txt file that has a list of matrices on it. For ex:

```
[6]

5 3        
6 2

7 8 -1     
4 3 1      
-2 0 3
```

and I need to read through this txt file and determine the determinant of each matrix and then output the matrix and its determinant to an output txt file. I am stuck with getting each matrix to be read and run through my determinate class and then outputted to the output txt file. How do I get each matrix separately and a matrix so that I can run it through my code?

This is what I have so far, but it just outputs each line to the output file and does not get each matrix as a matrix so I can find its determinant.

```java
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader (inputFilePath);                                   
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter (outputFilePath);                                             
    BR = new BufferedReader(fileReader);                                                                           
    try {                                                                                          
        String line = BR.readLine();                                                                            
        while (line != null) {                                                                           
            fileWriter.write(line + '\n');                                                                                             
            fileWriter.write("determinant= " + '\n');                                                                                                           
            line = BR.readLine();                                                                                              
        } 
        BR.close();                                                                                          
    } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                              
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                  
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far to read the matrices? Have you tried creating an `int[][]` to represent the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the matrices are made of integer values, you can read all lines and then for each line split by the whitespace and return as an array.

```java
       List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(inputFilePath));

       List<int[]> listOfMatrices = lines.stream()
                .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())
                .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output

```
[5, 3]
[6, 2]
[7, 8, -1]
[4, 3, 1]
[-2, 0, 3]
```

Comment: A `List<int[]>` isn't bad, but I'd prefer using an `int[][]` or a `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: My apologies, I could have swore you said a List of matrices, which I *presumed* translated to an *array*. I can easily update that. Edit; Done.

Comment: I didn't say anything about a list of matrices. Although if it is a list of matrices, it should be a 3D-ish structure, like a `List<int[][]>` instead

Comment: Sorry I thought you were OP, apologies

Comment: Yeah, I should have worded that differently. Still, from the formatting of the text file in the question, the matrices are `n x n` and not 1D arrays like you have. Each matrix is separated by a blank line, so you should probably change your code

Comment: I hadn't noticed that OP was separating matrices by **new lines**, i presumed the files were made up of single row matrices.