# File IO with matrices

Tags: java, matrix, file-io

I am trying to take in an input txt file and output the same file to a different txt file. However, I need to get each matrix on the input file to be out into a 2D array and after each matrix I want to write "Determinant: ". My code doesn't write anything to the output file the way it is right now. Why does it not work?

> `FileReader fileReader = new FileReader (inputFilePath); FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter (outputFilePath); BR = new BufferedReader(fileReader);`

```
        /**
         * We write out the matrices into the output file and create them to be reference matrix A
         */
        int c; // raw int value from input
        char nextChar; // input cast to char
        long start = System.nanoTime(); //start of execution in nanoseconds
        String line = BR.readLine();
        while((c = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
            nextChar = (char) c;
            int m= line.length();
            int[][]A = new int[m][m];
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; i < line.length(); j++) {
                    A[i][j] = nextChar;
                }
            }
            String mat = "Determinant: " + A;
            fileWriter.write(mat);
        } // end while
```

Comment: Duplicate post of one you made earlier; https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522216/4417924

Comment: @Jason I made some edits and wanted an updated post available

Comment: Your current code does not read input properly.  How are you going to handle negative numbers if you read input char by char?  You read the first line, then for each following char you create a square matrix filled with the same char? Then you write into a file (in a single line) "Determinant"+memory address of this square matrix.  Is it what you want?